# Laravel Controller - 'name' variable to get users 'email' – Not as a Logging in Technique

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-blade

I keep hitting a dead end on this, and I have been working 80hr weeks and need a little help.

I have a project which allows me to send loyalty points to my customers. I can enter their registered email address and enter an amount then click send, and it arrives in their account for spending on a coffee, etc.. which is a fully working process.

**BUT**, I require my form field to accept the user's email address **OR** alternatively their registered username.. just incase I cant remember their email address but can for their username.

In the database, the email address is stored under **email** and the users name for my customers is stored under **name** ... so i require **email** and **name** to both fetch the related email address **email** so the system submits the request correctly..

**Blade/Form**

```php
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
    <label for="email">{{__('Customers Email or Name')}}</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
class MoneyTransferController extends Controller
{
    public function sendMoneyForm(Request $request){
        return view('sendmoney.index');
}

public function sendMoney(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'amount'    =>  'required|numeric|between:1,5.00',
        'description'   =>  'required|string',
        'email' =>  'required|email|exists:users,email',
    ]);

    $currency = Currency::find(Auth::user()->currency_id);

    $auth_wallet = Auth::user()->walletByCurrencyId($currency->id);

    if((boolean)$currency == false ){
      flash(__('Failed!'), 'danger');
        return back();
    }

    if ( Auth::user()->account_status == 0 ) {
        flash(__('Try again') , 'info');
         return  back();
    }


    if ($request->email == Auth::user()->email) {
        flash(__('You cannot send points to yourself') , 'danger');
        return  back();
    } 

    if ($request->amount > $auth_wallet->amount) {
        flash(__('You have insufficient points to send').' <strong>Try again!</strong>', 'danger');
        return  back();
    }

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();







    $receive = Receive::create([
        'user_id'   =>   $user->id,
        'from_id'        => Auth::user()->id,
        'transaction_state_id'  =>  3, // waiting confirmation
        'gross'    =>  $request->amount,
        'currency_id' =>  $currency->id,
        'currency_symbol' =>  $currency->symbol,
        'fee'   =>  $receive_fee,
        'net'   =>  $request->amount - $receive_fee,
        'description'   =>  $request->description,
        'send_id'    =>  0
    ]);

    $send = Send::create([
        'user_id'   =>  Auth::user()->id,
        'to_id'        =>  $user->id,
        'transaction_state_id'  =>  3, // waiting confirmation 
        'gross'    =>  $request->amount,
        'currency_id' =>  $currency->id,
        'currency_symbol' =>  $currency->symbol,
        'fee'   =>  $send_fee,
        'net'   =>  $request->amount - $send_fee,
        'description'   =>  $request->description,
        'receive_id'    =>  $receive->id
    ]);

    $user->RecentActivity()->save($receive->Transactions()->create([
        'user_id' => $receive->user_id,
        'entity_id'   =>  $receive->id,
        'entity_name' =>  Auth::user()->name,
        'transaction_state_id'  =>  3, // waiting confirmation
        'money_flow'    => '+',
        'currency_id' =>  $currency->id,
        'currency_symbol' =>  $currency->symbol,
        'activity_title'    =>  'Payment Received',
        'gross' =>  $receive->gross,
        'fee'   =>  $receive->fee,
        'net'   =>  $receive->net,
    ]));

    Auth::user()->RecentActivity()->save($send->Transactions()->create([
        'user_id' =>  Auth::user()->id,
        'entity_id'   =>  $send->id,
        'entity_name' =>  $user->name,
        'transaction_state_id'  =>  3, // waiting confirmation
        'money_flow'    => '-',
        'currency_id' =>  $currency->id,
        'currency_symbol' =>  $currency->symbol,
        'activity_title'    =>  'Payment Sent',
        'gross' =>  $send->gross,
        'fee'   =>  $send->fee,
        'net'   =>  $send->net
    ]));

    return  redirect(route('home'));

}

public function sendMoneyConfirm(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'tid'   => 'required|numeric',
    ]);

    $transaction = Transaction::find($request->tid);

    $currency = Currency::find($transaction->currency_id);

    $auth_wallet = Auth::user()->walletByCurrencyId($currency->id);

    if((boolean)$transaction == false ){
        flash(__('Failed!'), 'danger');
        return back();
    }

    if ( Auth::user()->account_status == 0 ) {
        flash(__('pending') , 'info');
         return  back();
    }

    if(Auth::user()->id != $transaction->user_id ){
        flash(__('Failed!'), 'danger');
        return back();
    }

    $send = Send::find($transaction->transactionable_id);

     if((boolean)$send == false ){
        flash(__('Failed!'), 'danger');
        return back();
    }

    if(Auth::user()->id != $send->user_id ){
        flash(__('Failed!'),'danger');
        return back();
    }

    $receive = Receive::find($send->receive_id);

    if((boolean)$receive == false ){
        flash(__('Failed!'), 'danger');
        return back();
    }

    $user = User::find($receive->user_id);

    $user_wallet = $user->walletByCurrencyId($currency->id);

    if((boolean)$user == false ){
        flash(__('Failed!'), 'danger');
        return back();
    }

    $receive_transaction = transaction::where('transactionable_type', 'App\Models\Receive')->where('user_id', $user->id)->where('transaction_state_id', 3)->where('money_flow', '+')->where('transactionable_id', $receive->id)->first();

    if((boolean)$receive_transaction == false ){
        flash(__('Failed!'), 'danger');
        return back();
    }

    if((double)$auth_wallet->amount < (double)$transaction->net ){
         flash(__('You have insufficient points').' <strong></strong>', 'danger');
        return  back();
    }

    $receive->send_id = $send->id;
    $receive->transaction_state_id = 1;
    $receive->save();

    $send->transaction_state_id = 1;
    $send->save();

    $transaction->transaction_state_id = 1;
    $transaction->balance = (double)$auth_wallet->amount - (double)$transaction->net;
    $transaction->save();

    $receive_transaction->transaction_state_id = 1;
    $receive_transaction->balance =  (double)  $user_wallet->amount + $receive_transaction->net;
    $receive_transaction->save();

    $auth_wallet->amount = (double)$auth_wallet->amount - (double)$transaction->net ;
    $auth_wallet->save();

    $user_wallet->amount =  $user_wallet->amount + $receive_transaction->net ;
    $user_wallet->save();



    return  back();
}
```

}

I just need a solution so that if I enter the Username '**name**,' then it checks it against the user's registered email address and then continues processing it as normal as if the email had been entered.

Hope I make sense.. quite tired this end!

Thanks for any help - very appreciated.

---

Can it be done with some logic such as:

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->email);
if
$user = User::where('name', $request->name);
name =  $request->email
```

or even:

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first(); 
if (!$user) {
$user = User::where('name', $request->email)->first(); 
}
```

Both of which still dont work! owch!

in order to grab email address from a 'name' input..  any ideas please????

Comment: So you're expecting a query to check username for its existing email?

Comment: Thanks for your help! 

I have a form field which requires 'email' to process the function.. but i would also like it possible to enter the 'name' of my customer so that it processes it as if it was their email address being entered.. both 'email' and 'name' are in the same database record..

Answer (score 0):

//This will check user based on name

```
$user = User::where('name',$request->name)->first()
```

//$user is a collection of the user's details so the dd($user will output the email)

```
dd($user->email)
```

Comment: Does the query above get the user details based on username or email? @Rtech

Comment: hello.. it should get the user's 'email' based on 'name' .. im not having any luck figuring it out.. i have reviewed all of the controller code and it works with enterting email.. but if a user enters their 'name' then i need it to return their 'email' in the background as if it was inputted as their 'email' in the first instance.. hope that makes sense?

Comment: I assme the name should be unique column else there might be conflic while retrieving the email.

Comment: @Rtech i've update the code it should make more sense

Comment: Hi Lim.. Thank you ill test it now and let you know what occurs with it!

Comment: the page has stopped loading with that code inputted into the controller.. ill try and check whats why its crashing it..

Comment: it seems only       $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
            works  as this retrieves a users email..   i just cant get it to also accept the input of 'name' to retrieve a users 'email'  ... darn!

Comment: So the first method works as you requested, does it fulfill what you need? @Rtech. You need to make sure the name is unique or else wrong email might be captured in return

Comment: Sorry it's still not working.. would a solution along the lines of this work...

`code`

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();   
    if (!$user) {
 $user = User::where('name', $request->email)->first();
 }

`code` 

to try and get email from a possible 'name' entry into form..? have i coded that wrong?

Comment: Possible, how's the output?

Comment: The page just keeps refreshing blank with all the above examples.. i feel like such a newbie!

Comment: @Rtech the simple query above will take email based on name but name must be unique or wrong email will be return or there's any more column or input can be used to make more condition checking

Comment: Noted. Will improve on providing more detailed solution next time.

Comment: i definitely agree that this coding should solve my issue.. i just keep getting a plain page throwback when trying to implement it into the controller code listed in my opening post and i cant figure out why.. thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please show an example on how i would integrate your code into my current code of `code`$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first(); `code` so that it checks for **email** then if not present on user input then it checks for **name**

Comment: `code`$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->orWhere('name', $request->email)->first();
 `code`  is what im thinking but im still not getting it to work.. i may need to review all the controller coding in my first post

Answer (score 0):

```
  First you need to change the html form email type to text. dont forget to check manually if username or email exist

  <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
        <label for="email">{{__('Customers Email or Username')}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
    </div>

    public function sendMoney(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'amount' => 'required|numeric',
                'email' => 'required|string',
            ]);

        if(filter_var($request->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            if ($request->email == Auth::user()->email) {
                flash(__('You cannot send points to your own account'), 'danger');
                return back();
            }
 $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        } else {
            if ($request->email == Auth::user()->username) {
                flash(__('You cannot send points to your own account'), 'danger');
                return back();
            }
 $user = User::where('username', $request->email)->first();
        }
        }
```